# CSS Syntax to select multiple elements under a class

Tags: css

**HTML:**

```
<div class="home">
 <div class="a">
   A content
 </div>
 <div class="b">
   B content
 </div>
 <div class="c">
   C content
 </div>
 <div class="d">
   D content
 </div>
 <div class="e">
   E content
 </div>
</div>
```

To apply common styles for a,c and e children under home class we can use multiple css selectors as written below.

**CSS:**

```
.home .a,.home .c,.home .e{
 background-color:#ccc;
}
```

**Question:**
What is the shorter version of the above css?

Now as a c and e are common children of home. Instead of repeating `.home` again and again how can I write a shorter syntax to select class a, b and c that are under home class.

Maybe something like:

```
.home(.a,.c,.e){
 color:#ccc;
}
```

I know it is wrong but just gives a clear idea about my question here, what I am looking for.

Comment: I did edit my question to make it a bit more clear. I want only a specific set of classes under a div.

Comment: Are `a`, `c` and `e` just a random example or you need to specifically target those divs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code `.home(.a,.c,.e)` won't work, and there is no `OR` operator for CSS selectors. `home .a,.home .c,.home .e` is the shortest way.

But here a few selectors that might help you:

```
.home div { } /* all divs in home */
.home > div { } /* all divs that are a direct child of .home */
.home * { } /* all elements in .home */
.home > * { } /* all direct children of .home */
```

There also exist CSS preprocessors, like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) that give you more possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Use the child selector '>'.

CSS:

```
.home > div {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`div` with class `a`, `c` and `e` can be selected using `:nth-child` pseudoclass

```
.home > div:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

with the given markup this is equivalent to

```
.home .a, .home  .c, .home .e{
   background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbPNPw

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mention names of classes explicitly (e.g. `a, b, c`) but don't want repetition in your source css, maybe it's nice idea to start using some CSS-preprocessor, like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/). For example, with Sass you can write in .scss file this:

```
.home {
    .a, .c, .e {
        background-color:#ccc;
    }
}
```

On the output Sass will compile it to .css file:

```
.home .a, .home .c, .home .e{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

This will keep your source files clean.

Answer (score 1):

In current CSS, there is no such syntax.

CSS Selectors 4 [has `:matches` pseudo-class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#matches), that will be able to do such grouping:

```
.home:matches(.a,.c,.e){
 color:#ccc;
}
```

Unfortunately, it isn't supported by browsers yet. Gecko- and WebKit/Blink-based browsers have experimental implementation of an old draft as `:-moz-any()` and `-webkit-any()`, respectively, but you will have to write the selectors twice to get it working in these browsers only, so they are far from practical use now.

But you can simplify your CSS like this with CSS preprocessors.